# How to see Task Definition history for ECS Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, rollback, aws-fargate, ecs-taskdefinition

Is there a way to see the history of task definitions for an ECS service? It is easy to see the current task definition for the service as well as the current task definition for the tasks. But I can't see a way to see what the previous task definition registered with the service was. I can easily see all the task definitions I have, but I don't know which ones were registered to which service.

We can usually see the version because of the history of jobs in our Jenkins box. But we recently had a situation where Jenkins didn't have the history for the one we wanted to roll back to. We ended up guessing right because incrementing numbers are easy to guess. But I don't like that we had to guess. I couldn't see it in the CloudWatch logs. I could see the auto-scaling events there, but not task definition changes.

Comment: they have Stopped tab to see STOPPED tasks. You can use them to see history

Comment: True, but they stay there for a very short time. In our case, we were trying to roll back about 10 minutes after rolling forward and the STOPPED tasks tab was empty.